# Contar diferentes tablas en mysql COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy contando los registros de diferentes tablas que no tienen relación alguna
Ejemplo

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleados"
$sql2="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM administrativos"
```

Habrá alguna forma de unir estos conteos sin necesidad de hacer diferentes variables "$sql,$sql1" etc.
Tendrán alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Y luego qué haces con esas variables? las utilizas dentro de una clase o función?

Comment: Pues suponiendo que cada una tiene su query y una vez que todos los conteos se ejecutan sumo el resultado de cada conteo. ejemplo: $total= $resultado1+$resultado2, etc.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `UNION` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT
    SUM(count) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*) as count
    FROM empleados
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM administrativos
) AS t
```

En `total` tendrás la suma de ambos conteos.

### DEMO

[Ver prueba en línea (pulsar <kbd>Run</kbd> para ver los resultados)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gAk3uWEubMyYL4JEWumYVo/0).

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE empleados (
  id INT
);

CREATE TABLE administrativos (
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO empleados (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO empleados (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO empleados (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO empleados (id) VALUES (4);


INSERT INTO administrativos (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO administrativos (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO administrativos (id) VALUES (3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    SUM(count) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*) as count
    FROM empleados
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM administrativos
) AS t;


| total |
| ----- |
| 7     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gAk3uWEubMyYL4JEWumYVo/0)

Comment: Me arroja error: FUNCTION id17475595_escuela.SUM does not exist.

Comment: @karlDomínguez ese error debe venir de otra parte. Lo que es la consulta en sí misma la he probado y funciona prefectamente, [puedes verificarlo en este fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gAk3uWEubMyYL4JEWumYVo/0).

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano, me funcionó muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar de esta manera, a mi me funciono, acabo probar con mis dos tablas y me dio el resultado esperado, igual la respuesta de  @A.Cedano funciono con mis tablas

```
select sum(tmp.total)
        from
       (
        select count(*) as total from empleados
        UNION ALL
        select count(*) as total from administrativos
        )tmp;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D ya me funcionó